# outdoor wiring question

Tags: outdoor

hope someone can educate me on a few things. i would like to add an outlet to the far end of my pergola. i already have electrical on the pergola. i plan on using 3 single 12g wires. in emt conduit with exterior gang box. when i go to lowes i see the southwire rolls of wire. the label has thhn,thwn and one more item(i forgot what it was) my question is. since the label has thhn and thwn, does that mean it is rated for outdoors? or will thhn be good enough since its in conduit.  thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Conduit which is located outdoors is considered a wet location (even inside the conduit), so you would need THWN.

Comment: thats what i thought, but would you know if the label has thhn and thwn on it, does that mean it is thwn rated?

Comment: @cano Yup, if it has THWN on it, it's wet-rated.

Answer (score 1):

Most conductors are usually multiple rated. Meaning it's good for more than one application. Mmathis is right. The "W" in the rating (thw, thwn, xhhw, etc...) means it can be used in wet locations.

Comment: Can liquid tight conduit be used on short runs to get around an obstruction.  Does it need to be metal liquid tight? Or if i run the ground wire to the metal box after the flexible conduit,  would it be ok. Thanks

Comment: Any approved conduit can be run as a protection sleeve either metallic or non-metallic as long as you are running a ground with it. You can also run to a metal box as long as you attach the ground to the box.